# Angular Email Control valid even if the email format is inorrect

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Please check the code on : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-dirty-and-form-valid-check

It is a simple code :

HTML :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email])
  })
}
```

TS FILE :

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="registerNew()" class="text-center">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input
    [class.is-invalid]="registerForm.get('email').invalid && registerForm.get('email').touched"
    type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
    <br>
  <small *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').valid &&
                registerForm.get('email').dirty">
    Valid Email ID
  </small>
</form>
```

In this there seems to be a problem.

when I type the email : "a@gmail" without ".com", then also its shows the  tag saying that the email is valid.

Is is incorrect functionality or am I missing something here?

[image]
-Ashish

Comment: Understood, You mean to say that ".com" may or may not be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the question linked in my comment, not all hosts have a dot in the name. `gmail` is still a valid host or "domain", in the same sense that `localhost` is. If you have everything configured properly with a mail server running on localhost, you can send an email to `user@localhost`.